# JavaScript's Datejs library will not parse its own ISO format string

Tags: javascript, date, datejs, date-parsing, isodate

Javascript's Datejs library does not seem to want to parse its own ISO Format string:

```
Date.parse((new Date()).toISOString ( )) // Result is null
```

Is there another way I should be doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which browser are you using? I tried the syntax in the console of Firefox and it's returned a correct date value:

```
>>> Date.parse((new Date()).toISOString ( ))
Date {Mon Mar 19 2012 22:20:55 GMT+0100}
```

Comment: It was throwing errors in my code, but I put it in firefox's debugger to check before I posted.  I wonder if I have the wrong version of datejs or something?